# A simple way to change a byte to a string?

Tags: c#, string, hex, byte

For example if I had the values, I would want it to go, eg.:

```
0x0B -> "B"
0x10 -> "10"
```

Is there a simple built in way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`ToString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y11056e9.aspx) method with the "X" (uppercase hexadecimal) format specifier:

```
byte b = 0x0B;
string s = b.ToString("X");
```

See also [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx) for more details about format strings.